# Characterize all $\mathbb Z[i]$ modules of order $21$ and $65$

Tags: finite-groups, modules

I am trying to figure out how many $\mathbb Z[i]$ modules (up to isomorphisms) are of $21$ and $65$ elements. I've done a few similar exercises for finite abelian groups ($\mathbb Z$ modules) but I am pretty lost on how to apply the structure theorem with this particular ring. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First write down the abstract statement of the structure theorem. Then try to explicitly identify the ingredients in it in this case.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I've done that but I am still lost. I have seen two versions of the theorem. If $R$ is a PD and $M$ a finitely generated module, then $M \cong R^n \oplus R/\langle d_1 \rangle \oplus ... \oplus R/\langle d_m \rangle$ with $d_1|...|d_m$. The other version is $M \cong R^n  \oplus R/\langle {p_1}^{\alpha_1} \rangle \oplus ... \oplus R/\langle {p_m}^{\alpha_m} \rangle$ with $p_i$ irreducible.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I am absolutely lost at figuring out which are the ideals $\langle d_i \rangle$ or for example, at determining if $\mathbb Z[i]^n=0$ (n=0). I mean if these groups are seen as $\mathbb Z$ modules, then they are torsion modules since $|M|.m=0$ for all $m$. But with this ring I don't know, I don't even know how the action works.

Comment: Use the second version. What are the irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$? If a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module contains $\mathbb{Z}[i]^n, n \ge 1$ then show that it's not finite.

Comment: Thanks for the patience. I will think your first question. As for your second suggestion, by a cardinality argument ($M$ is of finite cardinal and $Z[i]^n$ is not)

Comment: Sorry to bother again, could you tell me or suggest me which are the irreducible elements in $\mathbb Z[i]$? I've been thinking about it but I couldn't arrive to anything.

Comment: I was assuming that that was something you would've covered in your course. It's a bit hard to do this without that knowledge. Do you know anything about which primes $p$ remain irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and which don't? For the purposes of this problem you only need to know the answer to this question for the prime divisors of $21$ and $65$ which you can work out by hand.

Comment: Well, there is the property "if $w \in \mathbb Z[i]: |w|^2 \in \mathbb Z$ is prime (in $\mathbb Z$), then it is prime in $\mathbb Z[i]$. But this is not the case for $3,5,7$ or $13$.

Comment: Are you sure? Recheck that.

Comment: Well, if $w=xy$ in $\mathbb Z[i]$, then $|w|^2=|x|^2|y|^2$. As $|w|^2$ is prime, it must be $|x|^2=1$ or $|y|^2=1$. Given this, it is easy to see that $x$ or $y$ are units in $\mathbb Z[i]$, so $w$ is irreducible (or prime). And, for example,$|3|^2=9$ which is not prime.

Comment: I mean recheck your claim about $3, 5, 7, 13$.

Comment: Well, $|3|^2=3^2, |5|^2=5^2$, etc. so they are not prime.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't say what I meant to say. What I meant to say is: try finding $w \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $|w|^2$ is equal to $3, 5, 7, 13$. You'll be able to do it for some of them but not others, but in any case you'll have found some irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: 5,13 but not 3 and 7, ok, I'll keep working from there, thanks again.